# Can't edit last line in restricted editing in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using the Restrict Editing feature in Word to limit what users can change in a document. When they go to format the area that is open for them to edit they can't change the formatting if they have the last line selected.

I can change formatting on all other lines and change create a new last line and edit above that. As soon as the last line before the Restrict Editing box ends is selected, it won't let you apply formatting like bold or centered.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the last line, Word has an (normally invisible) symbol which carries the section format.

A) put a return behind the last line. That moves that symbol in the next line (where they still can't edit it, but it  might not bother anyone). Or

B) have them select the text only up to the last character (a bit tedious), leaving that symbol out of the formatting